# Windows/Py3 stdout with only LR, not CRLF

Tags: python-3.x, newline, stdout

In some earlier Py3 version on Windows I could ensure stdout LF instead of CRLF by doing

```
import msvcrt
msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdout.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)
print("Whatever")
```

but that stopped working in some Py3.2+ version. The `end='\n'` parameter doesn't work either, so I'm guessing this is caused by either the OS or some low-level stuff. What is the preferred way to do it in Py3.3+?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys,os
sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', newline='')
print("Whatever")
```